# orientation issue for a single view iOS 6

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation

I have 7 view controllers in my application all are in Portrait mode. Now i need to display another view(8th view) which supports both the orientations. I have implemented these three methods but screen is not rotating in landscape mode. Please suggest me.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
 }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
 }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
 }
```

Comment: R u using your view controllers inside navigation controller

Comment: in iOS6 put the supported orientations into the `Info.plist` file or implement the `-application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method in your application delegate class, and everything will work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the following in the appDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {    

return self.rotateToLandScape ?
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown :
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

then you should set the self.rotateToLandScape to true in the 8th screen.